# Allow only one set of data from foreach loop in Laravel-5.4 controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How to allow only one set of data from an array in Laravel-5.4 controller:

```
foreach(Cart::content() as $cartitem) {
   if($cartitem->id === $id){
      do something....
   }
}
```

I want to take only the set of data from $cartitem when $cartitem->id === $id ($id is coming from request) and reject all other set of data from $cartitem. Set of data can be found anywhere (in any index) from the array.

Comment: can you show how your array look like?

Comment: Cart::content() where you get this??

Comment: @MahfuzShishir I am using LaravelShoppingcart package.

Comment: This method will return a Collection of CartItems which you can iterate. But one thing you have to remember. your collection contain any id object?

Comment: @urfusion its in object format, in in chrome jsonview->
{rowId:"8b523dd15035cdcb4ef379230ba71cd8",id: "2",name: "Beam 2",qty: 3,price: 45,options: {image: /images/products/default_product.png",available_quantity: 3},tax: 9.45,subtotal: 135}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `where()` of eloquent to achieve the same.

```
Cart::content()->where('id', $id);
```

Comment: Did the tricks for me! Thank you so much. Did not realize Cart will support the ->where() query. You are genius!

Comment: I wish I could that but my poor reputation is not allowing me :( but once my reputation increased i'll for sure.

Comment: @WasidHossain You can't maybr upvote but you should be able to accept answer as correct.

Comment: Done, sorry I thought accepting and voting up is the same :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that in the request you already query for that specific id from cart. This way you don't need this foreach loop.

```
foreach(Cart::content() as $cartitem) {
   if($cartitem->id === $id){
      $cartitem; // this is your item
      break; // break from loop you found it already so stop looping
   }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#cartsearch) you can use: (returns all items with id = 1)

```
$cart->search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
    return $cartItem->id === 1; // this will return all items with id = 1
});
```

Or [get](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#cartget) by rowId

```
$rowId = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'; // this is just demo code
Cart::get($rowId);
```

Comment: actually here I had to check with the available product's id from DB with the current Cart which would never match with "rowId" so I had to match with cart's saved 'id'. and also maintain all the cart in one view for all products.